# Python 3.7: What is the right way of using asyncio await within await?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, event-loop

So I need to have a code that gets a list of objects, where each object holds another list of objects:

```
[
{"another_list": [{}, {}]},
{"another_list": [{}, {}, {}]},
]
```

I want to gather responses on each level in parallel, and for the inner level I had used asyncio.run, async functions with await, and asyncio.gather.

For running the logic I had to run on each inner object - I used asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor()

The issue is - that on the outer level I used it the same way (where run_in_executor invokes the async logic for the inner level, including invoking asyncio.run *for each level*).

It **works**, but I wondered why I don't get an error for running asyncio.run twice for the same event loop.

So after debugging I found out that when doing the outer run_in_executor, I create a new thread for each inner list.

I'm feeling like I'm missing something and there's a better way of working with asyncio in python 3 for running in parallel on parents + children levels.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is rarely needed to spawn threads with async Python. GIL makes threads a bit... useless. Anyway instead of `run_in_executor` consider using combination of [asyncio.create_task()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) with `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: @freakish Thank you! create_task works great for invoking the inner lever from the outer level.
It doesn't fit if I'd like to invoke on the inner level a logic asynchronously, where the logic works from a synchronous python client.

Is there a way to await for its answer, other than creating a new thread ? looking for something similar to wrapping a sync function with promises in js

Comment: OK eventually I had wrapped my sync func with asyncio.coroutine and then I indeed worked with create task. thank you!